# Python file.csv read and transform in list

Tags: python, list, csv, reader

it's just a curiosity, I'm a python beginner. I'm from Brasil. If I execute my code, in this step `reader_list = list (reader)` not work, don not transform file in list. If I comment "for" block, it's okay, it's transform var `reader` in list. I want to know if open file and operate it, it's necessary open again, because if I open again in another var and repeat steps, It's work okay.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

file = open("planilha.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)

print(reader)
print(type(reader))

for row in reader:
    print(row)   

print("\n==================", end="\n\n")

reader_list = list(reader)
print("Keys:\t", reader_list[0])
print("Row 1:\t", reader_list[1])
print("Row 2:\t", reader_list[2])

file.close()
```

The output:

```
>>> %Run file_exemplo_pros_mano.py
>>> %Run file_exemplo_pros_mano.py
<_csv.reader object at 0x03D06870>
<class '_csv.reader'>
['Nome', 'Sobrenome', 'Sexo', 'Idade', 'Altura']
['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.72']
['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.73']
['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.74']
['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.75']
['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.76']
['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.77']

==================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tiago.martin\Documents\LetsCode_Python\file_exemplo_pros_mano.py", line 17, in <module>
    print("Keys:\t", reader_list[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Ok, if comment the "for row in reader: print(row)":

```
>>> %Run file_exemplo_pros_mano.py
<_csv.reader object at 0x041B5870>
<class '_csv.reader'>

==================

Keys:    ['Nome', 'Sobrenome', 'Sexo', 'Idade', 'Altura']
Row 1:   ['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.72']
Row 2:   ['Tiago', 'San Martin', 'Masculino', '34', '1.73']
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cvs.reader` returns an iterator.  After you consume all the rows in the `for` loop, the iterator is exhausted.  It is at the end.  So, calling `list(reader)` produces an empty list.  If you want to run through the file several times, convert it to a list FIRST, and then you can consume the list repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, it's perfect.